# How to Make Boxes Appear in HTML Using Divs?

Tags: html, css

Currently working on adding a page to a website, and what I want to do is make boxes appear in HTML on my site.

I've looked through the HTML and CSS and there does not seem to be any issues with formatting, syntax, etc. So, my question is **why won't the boxes appear?**

I'm trying to do something similar to this here:
[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/monir/pen/MYoMPZ)
    `.`

This is my HTML & CSS for the page

[Website HTML](https://gist.github.com/Freddie-V4/6744e24b76329ecc7d35)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Projects</title>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="inner">
        <h3 class="masthead-brand">FV4</h3>
          <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>

    <div class="mainContent">

      <div class="box">
        <h2>Title 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquam elit id tincidunt aliquet. Integer tincidunt sem ante, sed finibus erat efficitur maximus. Donec ultricies urna non felis rutrum, a suscipit lorem auctor.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <h2>Title 2</h2>
        <div class="box-banner"></div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <h2>Title 3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquam elit id tincidunt aliquet. Integer tincidunt sem ante, sed finibus erat efficitur maximus. Donec ultricies urna non felis rutrum, a suscipit lorem auctor.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <h2>Title 4</h2>
        <div class="box-banner"></div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <h2>Title 5</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquam elit id tincidunt aliquet. Integer tincidunt sem ante, sed finibus erat efficitur maximus. Donec ultricies urna non felis rutrum, a suscipit lorem auctor.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box no-text">
        <h2>Title 6</h2>
        <div class="box-banner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scripts/scripts.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Website CSS](https://gist.github.com/Freddie-V4/4c4cd992634124904d37)

```
/*
 * Globals
 */

@import 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700';


.mainContent{
  perspective: 80em;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box{
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;

  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px @shadowBlurRadius fade(@page-background-main-color, 35%);

  opacity: 0;
}
  h2 {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  p {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .box-banner{
    background: #CCCCCC;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0px -15px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    background-position: center center;
  }

  &.no-text .box-banner{
      height:129px;
  }

.toolbar{
  position: absolute;
  display:block;
  z-index:999;

  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width:100%;

  transform:scale(0);
}

.btn{
  font-size:1.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration:none;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  padding: 0px 10px 4px 10px;
  color: lighten(@page-background-main-color, 10%);
  display:block;

  &.left {
    float:left;
    font-weight:400;
  }

  &.right{
    float:right;
  }
}


a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  color: black; /*#bf0a0a*/
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */
.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 200px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 200px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}



/* Padding for spacing */
.inner {
  padding: 30px;
}

.headshot{
    width: 25%; /* you can use % */
    height: auto;
}


/*
 * Header
 */
.masthead-brand {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.masthead-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.masthead-nav > li + li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff; /* IE8 proofing */
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #a9a9a9;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
.masthead-nav > .active > a,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: black;
  border-bottom-color: #bf0a0a;
}

.masthead-nav > .active > a:hover {
  color: #bf0a0a;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .masthead-nav {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
 * Cover
 */

.cover {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

/*
 * Affix and center
 */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }

  .mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%; /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 700px;
  }
}

a .fa:hover{
    color: white;
}

/* HyperLink Style */
a:link {
  color: #BF0A0A;
        text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: #87CEEB;
        text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #780078;
        text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
  color: #FF0000;
        text-decoration: none;
}

/* End HyperLink Style */
```

And this is the only thing that appears when I open the index.html in my browser:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried removing `opacity:0` from your `.box` css?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaopWv

```
.box{
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;

  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px @shadowBlurRadius fade(@page-background-main-color, 35%);

  /*opacity: 0;*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run the code using HTML and CSS files attached.
Problem is with css file. In .box css declaration at line 27, opacity set to 0 because of which boxes are not visible. Change this to 1 and run the code again.

More about Opacity CSS:
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/opacity/